# Change Colours of Composition

Tags: after-effects, after-effects-expressions, color

So, I downloaded an after effects file with animated boxes, lets suppose for example there are three boxes , all 3 boxes are in three different composition. when I change colour of the box in one composition the color changes from all composition, I deleted expression value and disabled expression still somehow its all connected.

Comment: Can you share the after effects file, or add some screenshots? It's possible they're connected by some other expressions, or that one comp is being used to drive the other comps, but it's hard to say without seeing more

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is most likely that there is a single Box precomposed in its own comp. This comp is likely used in all the other comps, which is why every comp changes when changing the box at one place.

This is often the case in After-Effects presets or animation-packs, so that you can preview each comp with your footage without having to place it into each and every comp.

To circumvent that, locate the composition that contains the box. Press TAB and you will all the compositions in which this box-comp is used. Most likely, it will show many/all comps. Now copy the box (the layer, not the comp), go up one into the comp you want to render, delete the comp containing the box and paste the layer. It will now be separated since its outside the precomp.